# Simplest workflow to move a text-intensive excel database to different platform

Tags: python, html, excel, sqlite, html-table

I am confronted with the tasks of reviewing, amending, completing and translating a database prepared in MS Excel, which contains a sort of Bill of Material (BOM).
For each item, the document has a the following columns:

```
code/ID, short_description_ITA, long_description_ITA, short_description_ENG, long_description_ENG, unit_measure, quantity, unit_price, total
```

of which long_description contain long, textual descriptions (as name suggests).

The document/database is extremely unpractical to read and query and I am considering to move it to a different platform.

My question is: could you recommend one or a few alternative workflows, considering that:

a) I am fairly competent with `Python`/`Pandas`, enough to import, clean, export data to a `csv` format

b) I would be looking at using a platform that allows to generate an `html` output. This would allow to consult the document online, ideally in a form of html tables (which can be sorted, filtered, searched - or even tagged) of html documents

c) I ultimately have to export the database back into excel, to allow non-competent users to work with a familiar software.

d) I would be looking at performing repeated string substitutions, possibly using python's `re`.

I have considered using `sqlite` (which I could manage with Python), but I am still uncertain on the simplest method to go db -> html front-end (tables or one simple document)

Comment: whats the question ?

Comment: there's no shortage of python web frameworks.

Comment: @zython the question is: could you recommend possible workflows?

Comment: just read it out with pandas/xlwings put it into a sqlite database and hook it up some kind of webframework sanic/flask/bottle are all viable options